# Numerical integration on a hypercube

Tags: math, reference, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

Simple question, but hard to answer as it seems like. Is there a good library available which computes integrals over [0, 1)^d for arbitrary d? I can clearly do a simple integration over a regular grid, but this is extremely slow. I would prefer computational speed over accuracy here.

(As a bonus: It would be good if the library accepts a lambda (with &-capture) as an integrand.)

Comment: I would recommend looking into Gaussian quadrature and Legendre polynomials.  This is commonly done in finite element analysis to generate stiffness matricies.  Perhaps it's a good solution for your problem, too.

Comment: Have you tried Wolfram Alpha / Mathematica ?

Comment: Monte-Carlo with quasi-random generators like Sobel sequences. Here quasi-random is better as this fills the space more evenly than RNG that are designed to be more perfectly random. This improves the error from O(1/sqrt(N)) to O(1/N) where N is the number of samples.

Comment: https://github.com/stevengj/cubature